# Properly Handling Large Amounts of Data

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, datagridview

I've ventured into extremely unknown territory and I need some advice. I'm building an IRC bot for Twitch that could potentially contain hundreds of thousands of accounts. Previously I used Dictionary(of String, Integer) to store these accounts and their balance in memory, and just wrote them to a text file and saved it to disk. Now I'm storing a lot more data like their online time, whether they are a follower, or subscriber, how much they've donated. So I've started utilizing SQLite to store the accounts and I believe I need to utilize DataGridView with virtualmode to display these accounts and allow the user to edit any data. Am I on the right track so far? My aim is to keep it simple while managing larges amount of data, hopefully that wasn't an oxymoron.

Now I imagine the accounts in the SQLite database will need to be cached so that it's not constantly reading the database from the hard drive when a change needs to be made or when the user is scrolling through his list of accounts in the datagridview(which is in virtualmode). Am I right so far?

If there is another, more simpler method I could utilize please let me know, otherwise can someone help comprehend how I could cache these accounts? I did consider writing them to a Dictionary(of String, String) and then splitting the string when I needed to work with a specific value. Anyways I await your suggestions or comments.
Thank you.

Comment: This is a very broad question for anyone to answer as your issue can be handled many different ways. You mention there are large amounts of data, fine and that doesn't matter. What matter's most is what you actually need to do with it. Have you looked into classes etc to handle this? I would focus my attention on classes if you haven't done so already as you mention you are dealing with many other items. Then you can think about a Dictionary(Of Integer, yourclass) or a ListOf; where the integer is account id and yourclass is the object associated with that id...

Comment: Classes were another idea I was considering. I don't have much hands on experience with creating them. Would I create an account class and configure various properties to hold the values I needed? Then create a new account(class) for each account stored in my database?

Comment: please see my answer, it touches this information. Yes it's simple and little, but will put you on the right track to get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment above, you need to look into classes. See below for little example...

```
 Public Class Accounts
  Public Property AccountID As Integer = 0
  Public Property AccountName As String = String.Empty
  Public Property IsFollower As Boolean = False
  **'Add more properties as needed'**

  Public Sub New()

  End Sub

 End Class
```

Next you can do a call to your database and get all the id's from the table; you can use these to query the rest of your data for a specific id...

Loop through your id's that you have and get their data...

```
 Dim nAccount As Account = Nothing
 For each blah blah blah....
   nAccount = query from database... which will return your Account class object...
```

Now you can add this object (your account class) to a collection; for example a `Dictionary(Of Integer, Account)` Or `ListOf()`

As I have mentioned before there are a few different ways to go about this, it just depends on what you need to do and how you want to handle the data.

Comment: I'm convinced this is the way to do it. I'm going to start working on it now. Thank you.